# Awk rounding up numbers

Tags: shell, unix, awk

```
a=`echo 9.1200 | awk '{ if ($0 ~ /\./){ sub("0*$","",$0); sub ("\\.$","",$0);} print}'`
$a
```

the above `awk` returns 9.1 inside a shell script. But while executing the same awk in the unix console.
it returns the value as 9.12

Why `awk` rounding up the numbers and how to avoid this?

Below is the sample input and out file values

```
Sample input:
10
10.1
10.0
10.00
10.0000
10.0000000
10.58770
10.580
10.2555550003

Expected Output:
10
10.1
10
10
10
10
10.5877
10.58
10.2555550003
```

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: my desired output is 9.12

Comment: Is the script just supposed to remove redundant extra zeros? Can you provide some different inputs and the corresponding desired outputs?

Comment: cat regtest | sed -r 's/(00*)([^.0-9])/\2/g'

Comment: Updated the sample input and desired output

Comment: @Marjer Try to avoid using old and outdated back tics, use parentheses like this: `a=$(echo ....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk is not rounding up, you are stripping the last digit with your final sub() command. Look:

```
$ a=`echo 9.1200 | awk '{ if ($0 ~ /\./){ sub("0*$","",$0); sub ("\\.$","",$0);} print}'
$ echo $a
9.1

$ a=`echo 9.1200 | awk '{ if ($0 ~ /\./){ sub("0*$","",$0); sub ("[.]$","",$0);} print}'`
$ echo $a
9.12
```

There's several things wrong with your command line.

1. sub() takes an RE as it's first arg so the synopsis when using an explicit RE is `sub(/RE/,...)` not `sub("RE",...)` (google awk parsing string literals).
2. The 3rd arg for sub() is $0 by default so no need to explicitly add
   it.
3. You don't need multiple calls to sub() to strip the end of the
   string, just a simple ERE.
4. awk scripts are `<condition> { <action> }` blocks so don't put the
   condition inside the action block.
5. The natural way to convert a string to a number is just to use a
   numeric operator on it, not try to manipulate the string to look
   like a number.
6. Don't use deprecated backticks to invoke commands because, among other things, they interpret backslashes and so your awk command is seeing `sub("\.$"..` instead of your intended `sub("\\.$"..`.
7. Always quote shell variables

Here's a valid syntax to do what you're trying to do using string manipulation:

```
$ a=$(echo 9.1200 | awk '/\./{ gsub(/\.0*$/,""); print}')
$ echo "$a"
9.12
```

but this is simpler:

```
$ a=$(echo 9.1200 | awk '/\./{ print $0+0 }')
$ echo "$a"
9.12
```

and the test for `/\./` is not needed at all if your input data is always numeric:

```
$ a=$(echo 9.1200 | awk '{print $0+0}')
$ echo "$a"
9.12
```

The main problem you were having is in using backslashes so let me just address that for a bit. When you write an RE that includes an RE metacharacter such as `.` that you want treated as a literal character you have 2 options:

```
/\./
```

or

```
/[.]/
```

Let's assume you decide to use the former. All is well until you decide to use string delimiters instead of RE delimiters. A string literal is interpreted twice, once when the script is read and again when it is executed so to escape an RE metacharacter you need to escape it twice, e.g.:

```
"\\."
```

Now let's say you decide to invoke your awk script saving the output in a shell variable. You have 2 choices:

```
var=`awk '...'`
```

or:

```
var=$(awk '...')
```

When you use the latter there is no problem but when you use the former, that `...` syntax itself interprets pairs of backslashes as single backslashes so you need to add yet ANOTHER backslash to escape the `.`, i.e.:

```
var=`awk '... "\\\." ...'`
```

Obviously the escaping is getting out of hand.

So - to avoid backslash hell, when using REs use RE delimiters `/.../` whenever possible* instead of string delimiters `"..."` and when executing shell scripts use `$(...)` instead of the old style `...`.

* The time when you need string delimiters around an RE is when concatenating a literal RE segment with a variable or saving an RE in a variable, e.g. `var="a.b"; sub(var,"")` or `sub(var".*","")`.

Comment: There does appear to be a subtlety in that the OP's original code works with `$( )`. I know they're deprecated but it's confusing why this should change the behaviour of the awk command.

Comment: One of the differences between the using `\`...\`` and `$(...)` is that when using `\`...\``, 2 backslashes are interpreted as 1, but when using `$(...)`, 2 backslashes are treated as literally 2 backslashes. So when invoking awk the sub() sees `"\."` in the first case but `"\\."` in the second.

Comment: Thanks I updated my answer to make that point explicit and added a bunch of other information about REs in strings vs literals and escaping. I figure this comes up often enough it might as well get documented.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to remove leading and trailing zeros, this will do:

```
echo 09.1200 | awk '{ print +$0 }'
```

Or as some prefer (more widely compatible):

```
echo 09.1200 | awk '{ print $0+0 }'
```

Either of these two cause awk to convert the input into a number. (Note that [*the first one will not work on all versions of awk*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton).

Output in either case (using gawk):

```
9.12
```

For higher precision, you can use something like this:

```
awk '{ printf "%.12g\n", $0 }' file
```

Where `12` specifies the maximum number of decimal places.

As [@Jotne has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2341847/jotne), you should use `a=$(awk '{ printf "%.12g\n", $0 }' file)` rather than using backticks. Doing this results in your original code working, as well as the approaches that I have suggested.

Comment: `+$0` this was new.  Thanks for giving me some more `awk` tips and tricks.

Comment: `echo 9.1200 | awk '{ if ($0 ~ /\./){ sub("0*$","",$0); sub ("\\.$","",$0);} printf "%.12g\n", $0}'` Still the output is 9.1 in shell script

Comment: @Marjer have you tried either of my approaches instead? The last one is the most flexible but you may be able to get away with using one of the first ones (which are equivalent).

Comment: @TomFenech I have tried all the approaches, still my output is 9.1

Comment: @Marjer I can reproduce the issue using your code but not with mine.

Comment: @TomFenech `echo $f2 | awk '{ if ($0 ~ /\./){ sub("0*$","",$0); sub ("\\.$","",$0);} print}'|read FormatedF2value` it worked for me.

Comment: @Marjer OK but that's much more complicated than any of my suggestions and a completely unnecessary use of `read`. My answer contains an example, showing how you can assign the result to a variable. The key is not to use backticks (`) and instead use `a=$( )`. I recommend that you try my approach and let me know if it is still not producing the output you expect.

Comment: `+$0` will not work on nawk, /usr/xpg4/bin/awk and probably some other modern awks and it's ambiguous syntax so don't use it. Always use `$0+0` instead.

Comment: @Ed I believe we've had this discussion before! Anyway, I've edited to point out that the unary plus isn't as widely compatible.

Comment: Sounds good, I know you know about it but I commented to give the OP a heads up.

Comment: @EdMorton : doesn't work on `nawk` ??  `echo 9.120000 | nawk '$2 = +$1'   
9.120000 9.12`